# What is the efficiency of Nylon/Polyethylene artificial muscles?

Tags: polymers, materials-engineering

The only other [question in regards to this subject](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/artificial-muscles-and-their-efficiency) doesn't have a precise answer and it is more about actuators that directly convert electricity into mechanical force.

Nylon or polyethylene fibers, simply called "fishing lines" are thermoactive polymers that "contract" when exposed to temperatures around 130ºC, and thus, can be used like artificial muscles. [Here a simple video](https://youtu.be/UbvNW7ONiTc) showing it.

However, even though I saw a lot of videos on the subject, I couldn't find the efficiency of converting heat into mechanical work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not related to matter modelling.

Comment: Please add more context to the question details. Otherwise you risk this question being closed.

Comment: @VandanRevanur Added more details, I hope it is ok now.